# Group downloads by originating domain

Tags: google-chrome, download, download-manager

Can I automatically group downloads by domain (e.g. place it in corresponding folders inside `Downloads` directory)? I'm using Google Chrome and looks like it must be done by some sort of download manager.

- If this can be achieved with Chrome alone, how to do it?
- If not, what the best program for this task?

Comment: I have looked for something similar to this but have not found it so far. If you are of the programming type you could try making one either through chrome's extensions or a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to Firefox, you can use [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/), but they have no plans of porting to Chrome :(